# Boolean Algebra expression won't simplify consistently?

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I got this question on one of my exams recently and it's been annoying me ever since.

¬¬(A.B).¬B + ¬¬¬C

on the exam I put that

A.B.¬B + ¬C = 0 + ¬C = ¬C and left it there, and some of the online calculators I put it through give this answer, but others give a different answer e.g.

¬¬(A.B).¬B + ¬¬¬C

¬¬(A.B).¬B + ¬C

¬¬A.B + ¬B + ¬C

AB + ¬B + ¬C

A + ¬B + ¬C

and some classmates got this. Both methods seem correct, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If by this:

```
¬¬(A.B).¬B + ¬¬¬C
```

You understand this:

```
(((not not (A and B)) and (not B)) or (not not not C))
```

Then the simplest possible form we can get at is derived as follows:

```
    (((not not (A and B)) and (not B)) or (not not not C))
<=> (((A and B) and (not B)) or (not C))
<=> (((A and (not B)) AND (B and (not B))) or (not C))
<=> (((A and (not B)) AND false) or (not C)
<=> (false or (not C))
<=> not C
```

In the other derivation you give, the mistake is going from the 2nd line to the 3rd. The equivalence is lost in that step, the expressions are not equivalent. To see this, simply evaluate each expression for the assignment A=true, B=false, C=true and we can verify the first expression is false and the second is true:

```
    ((not not (A and B)) and (not B)) or (not C)
<=> ((not not (true and false)) and (not false)) or (not true)
<=> ((not not false) and (not false)) or (not true)
<=> (false and true) or (not true)
<=> false or false
<=> false
```

but

```
    ((not not A) and B) or (not B) or (not C)
<=> ((not not true) and false) or (not false) or (not true)
<=> (true and false) or (not false) or (not true)
<=> false or true or false
<=> true
```

If there is a rule they were trying to use in that step, they misused it.